# Java debugger find where an object was instantiated

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, anonymous-types

I'm debugging with Eclipse and got a parameter which is an anonymous-instantiated-interface. Is there a way to find out where it was created?

Comment: Search through the code. If you're using Eclipse, select the variable and press F3 key in order to check where it is declared (and probably instantiated).

Comment: if you use an advanced debugger/profile like yourkit java profiler, it can track object allocations and tell you exactly where they came from.

Comment: Or maybe use Find on Edit>Find/Replace

Comment: From the comment you made for my answer, the instance you want to know where it is instanciated is one that comes from a library (resteasy)? Add that information to your question, maybe someone will have a better solution knowing that directly from reading your question.

Answer (score 4):

While debuging you can see the actual stack trace in the Debug perspective, just click back down the trace from where the execution is stopping at a break point till you get to the method where the instance of the anonymous class was created.

[image]

here is the call that returned the instance

[image]

hit `F3` to locate the method.

[image]

Comment: This works if the thread that is stopped at the breakpoint is also the thread that created the object. But I've just hit a situation where an object is created by thread A and put on a job queue to be executed by thread B - in this scenario, B is stopped at a breakpoint, but B did not instantiate the object so the call to new is not on the stack. So this technique won't work in all scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you do a step by step debugging from the start of your application, there's no direct way to find out where it was instanciated using Eclipse.

The best way I've found to acheive that is to do a File Search (ctrl+h, File search tab) and search for `new "yourInterface"() {`, in all *.java files. This will find all places where you instanciate that interface in your code.

If you're able to reduce the scope with a working set, that will simplify finding which of the found places is the one you're looking for.

Comment: hm the problem is that it is created in code which instanciates the interface is in a library (resteasy) .. so i need to download all sourcecode and search there ?

Comment: in microsoft solutions there is a way to find memory leaks which shows where objects where created

Comment: Yes, for the search to work, you'll need the source code. You can try [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) but I haven't tried to find a specific instance and where in the code it could come from with it, so I'm unsure if it actually can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily modify your code to call this interface with any parameters (i.e. `null`) at the place where you get it, and do a step into.

**UPDATE**

`java.lang.reflect.Type` is a basic interface instances of which are loaded inside JVM. Locating this place (most probably it is native code) where they are instantiated in most cases will give nothing.

This type is used to describe generics in fields, methods, classes, etc. I.e. for a field declaration

```
List<? extends Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

it corresponds to `<? extends Foo>`. To find this declaration, you might want to:

- Call `toString()` in the debugger for this interface and search in your code for occurences
- Inspect this `Type` instance find out or to show us more info
- Use debugger to find out how it's being get with reflection (i.e. `Field.getType` or `Method.getGenericParameterTypes()`)

Comment: the problem is that the interface is java.lang.reflect.Type which has no functions =(

Answer (score 0):

i didn't track this prolbem further, because i used an other solution. But what me helped was this piece of code where the variable "genericType" was the anonymous-instantiated-interface:

```
// Ensure that we're handling only List<MediaEntity> objects.
boolean isWritable;
if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(type) && genericType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericType;
    Type[] actualTypeArgs = (parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments());
    isWritable = (actualTypeArgs.length == 1 && actualTypeArgs[0].equals(MediaEntity.class));
} else {
    isWritable = false;
}
```